# What does "Windows logo key + z" do in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

of course the first thing I did was to check out official statement from Microsoft : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

It says that Windows key + z will "Show the commands available in an app in full-screen mode."

I've accidentally pressed it but nothing happened. what exactly does this do?
I am just worried It made some changes to the system without me noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Win+Z was added in Windows 8 for the original full-screen "Metro" interface. It opens the [app bar](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-talks-about-the-app-bar-in-windows-8-apps/).